# Can A Qualifying Low Hand Also Win The High Hand Pot?

Tags: rules, omaha-hi-lo

For example, I was playing with a group of friends and one of the guys ended up with A-2-4-5-7 suited. He did win the low, but since it was also a flush he won both high and low pots. So my question is can you win both?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

Firstly, your hand has to *qualify* as being a low hand. Qualifying five-card poker hands must have no pairs in there, and also has no card higher than an eight.

As a player can only (and must) use two cards from their starting hand, there have to be at least three community cards available that are also no higher than an eight.

**Flushes and straights are ignored in low hands**, so your friend could indeed win the low and high pots.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first consider that only 2 cards of your 4 cards are used to make a Qualifying Low or Qualifying High in Omaha HiLo. The same 2 cards can be used for both your High and Low hands. So `YES`.

You can think about it as playing 2 different games with the same cards but with the same pot - Note that you may not have a `Qualifying LOW` all the time and there's always a `Qualifying HIGH` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to win both Hi and Lowe pots What comes to mind first is:
 If you have an Ace,2, and a 6,7, in your hand and the community cards are 3,4,5,j,10, then You win the low, A,2,3,4,5, and you wine the High with 3,4,5,6,7, (J+10 would be dead)

Or If you had a flush and a low hand. Say AS,2S, 8*, K*  and the community cards are 3D, 4D, 6S, 5S,JS, you would win a Flush and the Low hand. (* = any suit)

It is also possible to get a Full House and win a low with cards such as A, 2, 3, and 7,  If the community cards are  A,A,4,5,7, You would have the lowest hand with A,2,3,4,5, and a Full House with A,A,A,7 and 7.

Another scenario is this You have a 3,4,J, and a 10, and the flop is A,K,Q,2. and a 5, You could win high with A,K,Q, and your J, and 10, and a low with A,2,5< and your 3, and 4.

Sometimes these combination are what cause you to lose OR over bet on Omaha Hi/LO, If you are playing with a great low hand and one of the cards turns out to be a pair in the community cards then you might have been betting on two straights and the pair makes someone a Full House then you might have over bet, or If you are thinking you have the best low hand, and the person you are betting against also has the same low hand as you, (or better) and the high hand you will have to split YOUR LOW hand so YOU would only get 1/4th of the pot!

Really here I am showing you Mostly Pat hands. There are MANY combinations like this. Generally even when I have a low hand I will not bet on them, but I will keep up with the betting to win.  Pam